# Monthly average of data for a time series in a group by condition

Tags: r

Below is how my data looks like.

Date, City , Cost
Jan, New York, 1000
Feb, New York, 1500
Mar, New York, 1200
Apr, New York, 900
May, New York, 1100
June, New York, 1500
Jan, London, 2000
Feb, London, 2400
Mar, London, 1700
Apr, London, 1900
May, London, 1900
June, London, 1000

I want to calculate the below things:
1. % Cost change for last 3 months and last 6 months
2. Month by Month % Cost change for every group.

Hence, outcome will be like

Date, City , Cost
Jan, New York, 1000, 0%
Feb, New York, 1500 , 50%
Mar, New York, 1200 , -20%
Apr, New York, 900 , -25%
May, New York, 1100, 23%
June, New York, 1500, 36%
Jan, London, 2000 , 0%
Feb, London, 2400 , 20%
Mar, London, 1200 , -50%
Apr, London, 1200 , 0%
May, London, 1900 , 56%
June, London, 1900 , 0%
July, London, 1000 , -44%

and

City, Last 3 month change, Last 6 month change,
New York,-44% (1000-1900)/1900 , 58% (1000-2400)/2400
London, and so on...

Comment: There are major issues with your data & example that you still have not fixed: (1) Sample data and expected output don't match (e.g. `Mar London 1700` in input vs. `Mar London 1200` in output); (2) 3 months/6 months change `New York,-44% (1000-1900)/1900` There is no `Cost = 1900` entry for `New York`. (3) It's not clear how you want to calculate *"cost change for last 3 months and last 6 months"*. You need to give a clear & unambiguous example.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Concerning point 1: I'm unsure what you're after: 3 months, 6 months change relative to what? Concerning point 2: I can't reproduce your expected output. Please double-check your numbers.**

I assume you want to calculate the percentage change in `Cost` relative to the previous value. You can do the following using `dplyr::lag`:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    group_by(City) %>%
    mutate(perc_change = (Cost - lag(Cost)) / lag(Cost) * 100)
## A tibble: 12 x 4
## Groups:   City [2]
#   Date  City         Cost perc_change
#   <fct> <fct>       <int>       <dbl>
# 1 Jan   " New York"  1000        NA
# 2 Feb   " New York"  1500        50.0
# 3 Mar   " New York"  1200       -20.0
# 4 Apr   " New York"   900       -25.0
# 5 May   " New York"  1100        22.2
# 6 June  " New York"  1500        36.4
# 7 Jan   " London"    2000        NA
# 8 Feb   " London"    2400        20.0
# 9 Mar   " London"    1700       -29.2
#10 Apr   " London"    1900        11.8
#11 May   " London"    1900         0.
#12 June  " London"    1000       -47.4
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.csv(text  =
    "Date, City , Cost
Jan, New York, 1000
Feb, New York, 1500
Mar, New York, 1200
Apr, New York, 900
May, New York, 1100
June, New York, 1500
Jan, London, 2000
Feb, London, 2400
Mar, London, 1700
Apr, London, 1900
May, London, 1900
June, London, 1000", header = T)
```

Comment: 1:3 and 1:6 are basically last 3 month and last 6 month changes from the last3rd - last1 and last6th and last1, respectively for each group.

Comment: @Jay *"last 3 month and last 6 month changes from the last3rd - last1 and last6th and last1"* I have no idea what you mean. Also, can you double-check your numbers for the percentage change? I cannot completely reproduce your expected output.

Comment: @Jay From your OP: *"New York,-44% (1000-1900)/1900"* But there is no `Cost = 1900` entry for `New York`.

Comment: Apologies.. that was for London rather than New York.. my bad..

London,-44% (1000-1900)/1900

Comment: This result will be in a different structure, rather than the current one.

Comment: @Jay And the discrepancies in the monthly percentage change numbers for `London`? E.g. From `Mar = 1700` to `Apr = 1900` you give a `56%` change? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jay Lastly, numbers in your sample data and expected output are actually **different**. In your expected output for `London` you have `Mar` twice, but with different `Cost` values than in your sample data. This is a bit of a mess! I still don't understand your 3 months/6 months changes. I recommend taking some time **fixing the errors** in your sample & output data, and clarifying on what you'd like to calculate using clear & unambiguous examples.

Comment: The data is pretty messy.. 
here's the revised outcome. i have removed the second March for London, as data discrepancy.

Revised Outcome:

Date, City , Cost
Jan, New York, 1000, 0%
Feb, New York, 1500 , 50%
Mar, New York, 1200 , -20%
Apr, New York, 900 , -25%
May, New York, 1100, 23%
June, New York, 1500, 36%
Jan, London, 2000 , 0%
Feb, London, 2400 , 20%
Mar, London, 1200 , -50%
Apr, London, 1200 , 0%
May, London, 1900 , 56%
June, London, 1900 , 0%
July, London, 1000 , -44%

Now, i need to identify the %change for last 3 month, and last 6 month.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170026/discussion-between-jay-and-maurits-evers).